# object-node to element-node conversion fails?

Tags: javascript, marklogic

I am trying to set a default capability on a role in JavaScript like so:

```
declareUpdate(); 
var sec = require('/MarkLogic/security.xqy'); 
var pid = 3223704;
var role = 'scc-proj-' + pid + '-member';
sec.roleSetDefaultPermissions("scc-proj-3223704-member",(xdmp.permission("scc-proj-3223704-member", "read")));
```

This gives an error:

```
[javascript] XDMP-AS: $permissions as element(sec:permission)* -- Invalid coercion: object-node{"capability": text{"read"}, "roleId": text{"12999117528518422097...} as element(sec:permission)
```

If I look into it seems that `xdmp.permissions()` gives back an object node while `sec.roleSetDefaultPermissions()` expects an element node. So seems there is some type conversion not working...

The XQuery equivalent works okay.

1. Can this be fixed in javascript?
2. As a workaround can I run the XQuery from a javascript with xdmp.eval or invoke?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass `element` as the 3rd optional `$output-kind` parameter to `xdmp.permission`:

```
xdmp.permission("scc-proj-3223704-member", "read", "element");
```